# save zoom image level to file

Tags: java, gis, geotools

Let's say that I want to load an shp file, do my stuff on it and save the map as an image.

In order to save an image I am using:

```
public void saveImage(final MapContent map, final String file, final int imageWidth) {

      GTRenderer renderer = new StreamingRenderer();
      renderer.setMapContent(map);

      Rectangle imageBounds = null;
      ReferencedEnvelope mapBounds = null;

      try {
          mapBounds = map.getMaxBounds();
          double heightToWidth = mapBounds.getSpan(1) / mapBounds.getSpan(0);
          imageBounds = new Rectangle(0, 0, imageWidth, (int) Math.round(imageWidth * heightToWidth));
      } catch (Exception e) {
          // Failed to access map layers
          throw new RuntimeException(e);
      }

      BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(imageBounds.width, imageBounds.height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
      Graphics2D gr = image.createGraphics();
      gr.setPaint(Color.WHITE);
      gr.fill(imageBounds);

      try {
          renderer.paint(gr, imageBounds, mapBounds);
          File fileToSave = new File(file);
          ImageIO.write(image, "png", fileToSave);
      } catch (IOException e) {
          throw new RuntimeException(e);
      }
  }
```

But, let's say I am doing something like this:

```
...
MapContent map = new MapContent();
map.setTitle("TEST");
map.addLayer(layer);
map.addLayer(shpLayer);

// zoom into the line
MapViewport viewport = new MapViewport(featureCollection.getBounds());
map.setViewport(viewport);

saveImage(map, "/tmp/img.png", 800);
```

1) The problem is that the zoom level isn't saved on the image file.Is there a way to save it?

2) When I am doing `MapViewport(featureCollection.getBounds());` is there a way to extend a little bit the boundaries in order to have a better visual representation?

...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that you aren't saving the map at the current zoom level is that in your `saveImage` method you have the line:

```
mapBounds = map.getMaxBounds();
```

which always uses the full extent of the map, you can change this to

```
mapBounds = map.getViewport().getBounds();
```

You can expand a bounding box by something like:

```
    ReferencedEnvelope bounds = featureCollection.getBounds();
    double delta = bounds.getWidth()/20.0; //5% on each side
    bounds.expandBy(delta );
    MapViewport viewport = new MapViewport(bounds);
    map.setViewport(viewport );
```

A quicker (and easier) way to save a map from the GUI is to use a method like this which just saves exactly what is on the screen:

```
public void drawMapToImage(File outputFile, String outputType,
        JMapPane mapPane) {
    ImageOutputStream outputImageFile = null;
    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = null;
    try {
        fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
        outputImageFile = ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(fileOutputStream);
        RenderedImage bufferedImage = mapPane.getBaseImage();
        ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, outputType, outputImageFile);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (outputImageFile != null) {
                outputImageFile.flush();
                outputImageFile.close();
                fileOutputStream.flush();
                fileOutputStream.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {// don't care now
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice, thanks!Whatever value I tried  to divide with(`double delta = bounds.getWidth()/20.0`), didn't have any effect.So, I just use `double delta = bounds.getWidth()` and it works fine (it zooms out).Also, how am i supposed to use `JMapPane` in my case?Because I am using `MapContent`.Thanks!(upv)

Comment: Check in the debugger what the value of getwidth is? Dividing by 20 should give you 5% which maybe too small to show up

Comment: If you have a JMapFrame, you can get the mapPane from that, if not then don't worry about it.

Comment: `delta = 0.5` when using `bounds.getWidth()`. `bounds` has the values `maxx = 25.22, maxy = 38.7 minx = 24.72, miny = 37.17`.I think I will leave it like this, with no dividing.

Comment: :Hi!IDo you know if there is a function that takes a coordinate point and returns time / timezone?

Comment: I don't think so, you could find a shapefile of time zones and do a look up in that.

Comment: I opened a new [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45563712/time-from-coordinate-shp-file) for this!